# How to read a CSV file without using external libraries (such as Numpy, Pandas)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

This is a question that usually appears in interviews.

I know how to read csv files using `Pandas`.

However I am struggling to find a way to read files without using external libraries.

Does Python come with any module that would help read csv files?

Comment: A dataframe can be seen as a collection of records or as a list of columns. Numpy (and pandas) are mainly C or Cython optimizations to speedup the processing of large data frames, but you implement everything *by hand*. Only posting a comment because the current question is rather broad.

Answer (score 15):

You most likely **will need** a library to read a CSV file. While you could potentially open and parse the data yourself, this would be tedious and time consuming. Luckily python comes with a standard `csv` module that you won't have to pip install! You can read your file in like this:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    my_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in my_reader:
        print(row)
```

This will show you that each `row` is being read in as a list. You can then process it based on index! There are other ways to read in data too as described at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html one of which will create a dictionary instead of a list!

## update

You linked your github for the project I took the snip

```
product_id,product_name,aisle_id,department_id
9327,Garlic Powder,104,13
17461,Air Chilled Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts,35,12
17668,Unsweetened Chocolate Almond Breeze Almond Milk,91,16
28985,Michigan Organic Kale,83,4
32665,Organic Ezekiel 49 Bread Cinnamon Raisin,112,3
33120,Organic Egg Whites,86,16
45918,Coconut Butter,19,13
46667,Organic Ginger Root,83,4
46842,Plain Pre-Sliced Bagels,93,3
```

Saved it as `file.csv` and ran it with the above code I posted. Result:

```
['product_id', 'product_name', 'aisle_id', 'department_id']
['9327', 'Garlic Powder', '104', '13']
['17461', 'Air Chilled Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts', '35', '12']
['17668', 'Unsweetened Chocolate Almond Breeze Almond Milk', '91', '16']
['28985', 'Michigan Organic Kale', '83', '4']
['32665', 'Organic Ezekiel 49 Bread Cinnamon Raisin', '112', '3']
['33120', 'Organic Egg Whites', '86', '16']
['45918', 'Coconut Butter', '19', '13']
['46667', 'Organic Ginger Root', '83', '4']
['46842', 'Plain Pre-Sliced Bagels', '93', '3']
```

This does what you have asked in your question. I am not going to do your project for you, you should be able to work it from here.

Comment: What if I am supposed to use only Input and Output Libraries. Can I use an import CSV library?

Comment: @MosaliHarshaVardhanReddy What do you mean by "Input and Output Libraries"? `csv` comes with a `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` method. Does this make it qualify as an "Input and Output Library"?

Comment: Instead of using the CSV reader. I may have to use the file.reader("file.csv") and convert it into a DataFrame

Comment: I am confused. You want a DataFrame, but you refuse to use `numpy`. I don't think you can have it both ways...DataFrames are `numpy` specific as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @MosaliHarshaVardhanReddy So you are saying it is a requirement for you to parse the data yourself? And you are not allowed to use even standard Python library modules? I guess to make a dataframe the best you could do is make a list of lists

Comment: Yeah, I need to make a list of lists and then map them with the corresponding values. I am able to make some progress. I will post a GitHub link after I do my analysis in the comment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MosaliHarshaVardhanReddy I would truly urge you to use the `csv` module unless specified otherwise (which in your post you say only `numpy` and `pandas` are excluded). Then you can either make an sql database using `sqlite3` or make a list of lists or a list of dictionaries to represent your data for analysis. I see no reason you should not be able to import anything at all. If that is the case though you're in for a helluva hard project that will be tedious and time consuming and neglect the best part of python: *not having to reinvent the wheel with each program*

Comment: @MosaliHarshaVardhanReddy Nice job. Good luck on your interview then!

Answer (score 2):

Recently I got a very similar question that was made more complicated than this one on making a data structure without using pandas. This is the only relevant question I have found so far. If I take this question, then what I was asked was: put the product id as keys to a dictionary and then put list of tuples of aisle and department ids as values (in python). The dictionary is the required dataframe. Of course I could not do it in 15 min (rather in 2 hours). 
It is hard for me to  think of outside of numpy and pandas.

I have the following solutions, which also answers this question in the beginning. Probably not ideal but got what I needed.
Hopefully this helps too.

```
import csv
file =  open('data.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)

items = []  # put the rows in csv to a list
aisle_dept_id = []  # to have a tuple of aisle and dept ids
mydict = {} # porudtc id as keys and list of above tuple as values in a dictionary

product_id, aisle_id, department_id, product_name = [], [], [], []

for row in reader:
    items.append(row)

for i  in range(1, len(items)):
    product_id.append(items[i][0])
    aisle_id.append(items[i][1])
    department_id.append(items[i][2])
    product_name.append(items[i][3])

for item1, item2 in zip(aisle_id, department_id):
    aisle_dept_id.append((item1, item2))
for item1, item2 in zip(product_id, aisle_dept_id):
    mydict.update({item1: [item2]})
```

With the output,

```
mydict:
{'9327': [('104', '13')],
 '17461': [('35', '12')],
 '17668': [('91', '16')],
 '28985': [('83', '4')],
 '32665': [('112', '3')],
 '33120': [('86', '16')],
 '45918': [('19', '13')],
 '46667': [('83', '4')],
 '46842': [('93', '3')]}
```

Answer (score 2):

When one's production environment is limited by memory, being able to read and manage data without importing additional libraries may be helpful.

In order to achieve that, the built in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module does the work.

```
import csv
```

There are at least two ways one might do that: using `csv.Reader()` or using `csv.DictReader()`.

`csv.Reader()` allows you to access CSV data using indexes and is ideal for simple CSV files ([Source](https://realpython.com/lessons/reading-csvs-pythons-csv-module/)).

`csv.DictReader()` on the other hand is friendlier and easy to use, especially when working with large CSV files ([Source](https://realpython.com/lessons/reading-csvs-pythons-csv-module/)).

Here's how to do it with `csv.Reader()`

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print(', '.join(row))
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Here's how to do it with `csv.DictReader()`

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
...
Eric Idle
John Cleese

>>> print(row)
{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Cleese'}
```

For another example, [check Real Python's page here](https://realpython.com/lessons/reading-csvs-pythons-csv-module/).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar requirement and came up with this solution; a function that converts csv to json (needed json for readability and to make querying the data easier without having access to Pandas). If the `headers` arguement of the function is `True`, the first row of the csv is used keys in the json, otherwise value indices are used as keys.

```
from csv import reader as csv_reader

def csv_to_json(csv_path: str, headers: bool) -> list:
  '''Convert data from a csv to json'''
  # store json data
  json_data = []
  
  try:
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as file:
      reader = csv_reader(file)
      # set column names using first row
      if headers:
        columns = next(reader)
      
      # convert csv to json
      for row in reader:
        row_data = {}
        for i in range(len(row)):
          # set key names
          if headers:
            row_key = columns[i].lower()
          else: 
            row_key = i
          # set key/value
          row_data[row_key] = row[i]
        # add data to json store 
        json_data.append(row_data)
        
  # error handling
  except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
    
  return json_data
```

Given a csv containing the following

```
+------+-------+------+
| Year | Month | Week |
+------+-------+------+
| 2020 |    11 |   11 |
| 2020 |    12 |   12 |
+------+-------+------+
```

The output with headers is

```
[
  {"year": 2020, "month": 11, "week": 11},
  {"year": 2020, "month": 12, "week": 12}
]
```

The ouput without headers is

```
[
  {"0": 2020, "1": 11, "2": 11},
  {"0": 2020, "1": 12, "2": 12}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions are inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804). The output content in the examples below is generated using the following input data:

**data.csv**

```
Id,name,age,height,weight
1,Alice,20,62,120.6
2,Freddie,21,74,190.6
3,Bob,17,68,120.0
```

In case you would like to **pretty print** the output in the examples given below, you could use the following:

```py
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

### Solution 1 - Use [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to get a list of `list` objects

```py
import csv


def read_csv(filepath: str):
    data = []
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:             
            data.append(row)  
        
    return data
        
        
data = read_csv('data.csv')
print(data)
```

**Output**

```json
[['Id', 'name', 'age', 'height', 'weight'], ['1', 'Alice', '20', '62', '120.6'],
 ['2', 'Freddie', '21', '74', '190.6'], ['3', 'Bob', '17', '68', '120.0']]
```

To print the data line by line, you could also use the following:

```py
print('\n'.join(', '.join(map(str,row)) for row in data))
```

Output:

```
Id, name, age, height, weight
1, Alice, 20, 62, 120.6
2, Freddie, 21, 74, 190.6
3, Bob, 17, 68, 120.0
```

### Solution 2 - Use [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to get a list of `dict` objects

```py
import codecs
import csv


def read_csv(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(f, 'utf-8'))
        data = list(reader)
        
    return data
        
        
data = read_csv('data.csv')
print(data)
```

**Output**

```json
[{'Id': '1', 'name': 'Alice', 'age': '20', 'height': '62', 'weight': '120.6'}, 
 {'Id': '2', 'name': 'Freddie', 'age': '21', 'height': '74', 'weight': '190.6'}, 
 {'Id': '3', 'name': 'Bob', 'age': '17', 'height': '68', 'weight': '120.0'}]
```

### Solution 3 - Use [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to get a dictionary  of `dict` objects based on a primary key

```py
import codecs
import csv


def read_csv(filepath):
    data = {}
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(f, 'utf-8'))
        for row in reader:             
            key = row['Id']  # Assuming a column named 'Id' to be the primary key
            data[key] = row  
        
    return data
        
        
data = read_csv('data.csv')
print(data)
```

**Output**

```json
{'1': {'Id': '1', 'name': 'Alice', 'age': '20', 'height': '62', 'weight': '120.6'}, 
 '2': {'Id': '2', 'name': 'Freddie', 'age': '21', 'height': '74', 'weight': '190.6'}, 
 '3': {'Id': '3', 'name': 'Bob', 'age': '17', 'height': '68', 'weight': '120.0'}}
```

**Pretty printed** output (using the code mentioned at the top of this answer):

```json
{
    "1": {
        "Id": "1",
        "age": "20",
        "height": "62",
        "name": "Alice",
        "weight": "120.6"
    },
    "2": {
        "Id": "2",
        "age": "21",
        "height": "74",
        "name": "Freddie",
        "weight": "190.6"
    },
    "3": {
        "Id": "3",
        "age": "17",
        "height": "68",
        "name": "Bob",
        "weight": "120.0"
    }
}
```