# SyntaxError with pd.read_csv

Tags: pandas, syntax, syntax-error

I tried several times, but I couldn't find the error. [This is the error I've been having...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfkQQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try csv module and see if it will give you the same error?

```
import csv

with open('Stichprobe.csv', 'r') as file:
    my_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in my_reader:
        print(row)
```

Source:

[Read a CSV file and perform data analysis without using any libraries like Numpy and Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404141/read-a-csv-file-and-perform-data-analysis-without-using-any-libraries-like-numpy)

Comment: It still keeps giving me the same result:                                                                             File "<ipython-input-6-a6adc292e386>", line 3
    d_data = pd.read_csv('Stichprobe.csv'⁩).compute()
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier.

Comment: Normally, this kind of error happens when you have extract parenthesis somewhere. Example: d_data = pd.read_csv('Stichprobe.csv'))). Have you tried restarting the python kernel or better yet restarting your computer?

Comment: By your suggestion, I just restarted my computer. Nevertheless, still the same error.

Comment: is this the first time that you are using pd.read_csv? Can you run this code to see what is the python version you are using? — 
from sys import version
print(f"sys.version: {version}")

Comment: yes, this is the first time that I use pd.reas_csv. This is my python version : sys.version: 3.7.4

Comment: Sorry, I'm think I'm unable to help you in this question.