# How can I open a csv excel file from python without using different any modules such as the import csv and panda

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have a csv Excel data set which is related to Some Coivid-19 stats organised with headings and values under for example number of `covid` related deaths and the numbers under. The goal is to get the values and then calculate the averages of the columns.

The query is how can I open the csv file from Python thonny and calculate the averages of the columns. without using "Import csv" or any other modules such as panda.

this is what I have got so far.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Kaoma Kabange\Documents\CITS1401\LAB0\Covid-data-for-project_1_sample (1).csv','r') as f:
f_contents = f.read()
print(f_contents)
```

I have searched everywhere to find a solution, but most YouTube video's i watch used import csv,panda or other modules.
just looking to be pointed in the right direction :)!

this link below is an example of the data set.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksxEi.png

Comment: This is probably already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404281/8277795).

Comment: You can just read the file as you would any text file then parse the string yourself.

`with open('my_file.csv') as f:
     file_string = f.read()
`

Comment: @Anurag That solution won't work if the data contains the separator in quoted strings.

Comment: If so why do you don't want to use pandas.read_excel method. Can you provide an example set of the csv file.

Comment: Hey @AnuragDhadse I just want to try and do it without those libraries, because that is what is specified for the task. And I have attached the sample image above^.

Comment: and thanks @vodbeke i tried that and it returned my whole data set which is the first great ! thanks.