# How to read DD/MM/YY data directly from a csv file in python? (without using panda)

Tags: python, csv, datetime, syntax

I need to read in data values of format "1/2/16" for example, where it represents the date 01-02-2016 in mm-dd-yyyy format. I have a csv with each column of the form "11/2/16, 0.78" for example with a value associated to the date. How should I go about loading my dates and values to plot and look for a trend.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404141/how-to-read-a-csv-file-without-using-external-libraries-such-as-numpy-pandas.

Comment: I assume each line is stored in variable `line`, the you can get the date in this way:`line.split(',')[0].split('/')`.
It will give you a list containing `"11", "2", "16"`. If you want them to be `int`, then, this will work: `map(int,line.split(',')[0].split('/') )`

Comment: Can you show something you tried first? For reading a csv in Python, actually you do not need *any* libraries (but likely you gonna use them to get more robust code). For parsing date/time, you have the datetime library with strptime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can be used just by using built-in python methods.

---

If your date is in the format `mm/dd/yy, x.xx`, eg: `"11/2/16, 0.78"`, you can use the below code to extract `mm` (month), `dd` (date) and `yy` (year)

```py
date = "11/2/16, 0.78"
mm, dd, yy = map(int, date.split(",")[0].split("/"))
print(mm, dd, yy)
```

If you run the above code, it outputs:

```py
>>> 11 2 16
```

---

But you have also mentioned another format, ie `mm-dd-yyyy`. If you use this format, refer below code

```py
date = "11-2-2016"
mm, dd, yyyy = map(int, date.split("-"))
print(mm, dd, yyyy)
```

If you run the above code, it outputs:

```py
>>> 11 2 2016
```